# A rather naff limitation of ropemacs encountered with multiple name bindings

Tags: emacs, alias, code-completion, ropemacs

I am getting some disappointing *completion* and *go-to-definition* results with **ropemacs** in places where I use multiple name-bindings to the same object.

Considering my contrived and stylistically challenged example code below, does anyone know why **rope** would not be presenting completions or go-to-definition results?

**Project code sample:**

```
from Package import BigObjectWithLotsOfMethods

class GLOBAL:
    variable = None

big = BigObjectWithLotsOfMethods()
GLOBAL.variable = big
```

**Emacs behaviour in question:**

When I enter:

```
big.
```

then type <kbd>M-/</kbd>, I get a list of candidate method names as expected. Hurray for rope!

Yet on the other hand when I enter:

```
GLOBAL.variable.
```

for example, and then type <kbd>M-/</kbd> I get the following in the Emacs minibuffer:

```
Completions for GLOBAL.variable.: [No Match]
```

Furthermore, please imagine `fire()` was a method of `BigObjectWithLotsOfMethods` then typing <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>g</kbd> on the code `GLOBAL.variable.fire()` does not take me to the definition of `fire()` as expected but rather just outputs the following in the Emacs minibuffer:

```
Cannot find the definition!
```

Since `GLOBAL.variable` represents simply another name binding to the `BigObjectWithLotsOfMethods` instance I am surprised that rope is not doing something intelligent like inferring the definition from what it knows about `big`.

**The question:**

Why is such an apparently trivial level of support for code introspection in the presence of multiple name binding not working under rope? Am I missing something fundamental in my rope project configuration that addresses this for example?

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

One would imagine that because you are introducing one level of indirection, that rope no longer is smart.

Note I haven't played with Rope in a while because I found it getting in the way more than it helped.  Also it was a bit slow.  Mostly using `M-/` with a combination of pyflakes/flymake instead on emacs.  (One downside to `M-/` being that you have to type the method out the first time).  Of course if Rope started giving more bang and costing less buck, I might be tempted to revisit it.

I wonder if the py-dev, pycharm engines are smart enough to handle that.